# Merging Python lists fails

Tags: python, list, merge, ping, icmp

So I'm having some trouble with these Python lists I am trying merge together. I am trying to write an algorithm to check if the machine is connected to the internet. So I ping different Google servers and if none of them responds I assume the machine is offline.

The script I am using to ping the servers is a rewrite I made of another script and it can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/luizfb/6958733). The `echo()` function sends one ping and returns either the response delay (in seconds) or `None` if it fails. The `recursive()` functions sends multiple pings and returns a list with the responses from `echo()` (e.g. `[0.054, 0.134, None, 0.037]`).

The `recursive` function (short of docstring and some tired comments):

```
def recursive(dest_addr, count=4, timeout=1, verbose=False):

    if verbose:
        print("PING {} ; SEQUENCE {} ; TIMEOUT {}s".format(dest_addr, count, timeout))
        nrc = 0

    log = []
    for i in xrange(count):
        log.append(echo(dest_addr, timeout))
        if verbose:
            if log[-1] is None:
                print("Echo Request Failed...")
                nrc += 1
            else:
                print("Echo Received:  sequence_id={}  delay={} ms").format(i, round(log[-1]*1000, 3))

    return log
```

So when I ping these servers, I get multiple lists of those, and attempt to merge them like so:

```
results = recursive("google.ca")  # North America
results = results.extend(recursive("google.com.br"))  # South America
```

Doing that renders me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

I would like to know **why** that is happening.

*Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Apparently the recursive function returns `None` (instead of a list possibly containing `None`s)

Comment: `list.extend` modifies the list in-place and returns `None`, so no need to reassign the `list.extend` to any variable.

Comment: @AloisMahdal That would raise `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable`, not `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'`

Comment: @hcwhsa `x = None; x.extend()` returns AttributeError.  What you say in your comment might be true in the next (third) line, which Luiz hasn't shown us yet :), and which tries to call `extend` again.  I must say it makes a lot of sense, though...

Comment: @hcwhsa is right, I removed the variable reassignments and it worked. That function was returning `None` so on the third line (which is the same as the second one), the exception was throwned because I reassigned the `None` return value to the variable. Thanks a lot, if you repost this as a question I will galdly mark yours as the right answer. Cheers.

Comment: @LuizBerti Glad that helped, you can accept Alois Mahdal's answer. ;-)

Comment: @hcwhsa It seems that crystall balls actually **do** work sometimes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the exception is really raised from the code you presented (I assume it's the second line), then the only way how I can explain the AttributeError is that the recursive() function actually returned `None`.

However, as @hcwsha pointed out, extend() itself returns None and you do store it in the `results`, so if there is at least one line similar to that one, it definitely causes the culprit.